# Replacing a combination of terms

Tags: formatting, replacement

I have a quite simple question. I have an expression that looks similar to
$T=\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_2}+1$ and I'd like Mathematica to use $A=\frac{a_1}{a_2}$ to reformat the expression (if possible) such that only $A$ appears in it.

Any idea?

Cheers,
Pascal

Comment: Does this help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/894/131 ?

Comment: Sorry, but no. The example used in the mentioned thread is way to elaborate for me to understand.

Comment: If you could transform your expression in something depending on A only that would mean that the original expression would not change if I'd multiply both a1 and a2 with the same constant (A = a1/a2 = (c a1)/(c a2) ). Clearly, making that change to the original variables does change T. So, the transformation you want isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your expression and a rule for replacement:

```
T = 1/a1 - 1/a2;
rule = a1 -> A*a2;
```

Let us replace:

```
T /. rule
```

You get this:

> -(1/a2) + 1/(A a2)

You may further transform it. For example:

```
% // Factor
```

The result is:

> -((-1 + A)/(A a2))