# Substitution in expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

As the title suggests, I want in an expression to to some substitutions. For example in the expression $\mathcal{L}^+_0+\mathcal{L}^-_0+\mathcal{L}^+_0+\mathcal{L}^-_0+\mathcal{L}_1$ I want to substitute $\mathcal{L}^+_0+\mathcal{L}^-_0\rightarrow A$ and $\mathcal{L}^+_0+\mathcal{L}^-_0+\mathcal{L}_1\rightarrow B$. Obviously I cannot solve for $\mathcal{L}_0^i$ and then substitute, because then it will substitute *every*  $\mathcal{L}_0^i$.

I think that it can be solved with some short of pattern matching but my skills stop there.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is far too generic. Show us an example of  your expression in actual code.

Comment: Perhaps look into: [Can I simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/27951), and [Replace expressions with symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/894/27951)?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Somewhere on site I believe there's a simple answer that says if you want to apply substitution based on the identity `a + b == c`, instead of applying `a + b -> c`, use `a -> b - c`.  But I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the notation $\mathcal{L}_0^+=$`L0p`, $\mathcal{L}_0^-=$`L0m`, $\mathcal{L}_1=$`L1`.

You could solve for the L expressions with

```
Solve[{L0p + L0m == A, L0p + L0m + L1 == B}, {L0p, L1}]
```

> {{L0p -> A - L0m, L1 -> -A + B}}

and then substitute with

```
Expand[L0p + L0m + L0p + L0m + L1 /. {L0p -> A - L0m, L1 -> B - A}]
```

> A + B

Alternatively,

```
Solve[{L0p + L0m == A, L0p + L0m + L1 == B}, {L0m, L1}]
```

> {{L0m -> A - L0p, L1 -> -A + B}}

```
Expand[L0p + L0m + L0p + L0m + L1 /. {L0m -> A - L0p, L1 -> B - A}]
```

> A + B

You seem to suggest that this method does not work for you. Can you give an example where this method gives the wrong answer?

Comment: Hey thank you. Yeah, it's wrong to do it like this because the example that I gave is just representative. I expect to have even more complicated expressions than the one I gave, and therefore I can't base on this method.

Comment: Can you please give an example to work with?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. Could you look above my discussion with kglr. There I explain what I want to get. If not I can provide you with more info. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) (to prevent `a + b + a + b + c` from evaluating to `2 a + 2 b + c`) and [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) :

```
ClearAll[a, b, c]
Defer[a + b + a + b + c] //. {a + b + c -> A, a + b -> B}
```

> A + B

Alternatively, you can use [`Unevaluated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) in place of `Defer`:

```
Unevaluated[a + b + a + b + c] //. {a + b + c -> A, a + b -> B}
```

> A + B

Or a sequence of `ReplaceAll`s in place of `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
Unevaluated[a + b + a + b + c] /. a + b + c -> A /. a + b -> B
```

> A + B

You can also use a combination of [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html), [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) and [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html):

```
ClearAll[a, b, c]
HoldForm[a + b + a + b + c] //. {a + b + c -> A, a + b -> B} // ReleaseHold
```

> A + B

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. The first one seems to work but I have one question: what is `//.`? Whats the difference with `./`? Additionally what happens if for example I have the expression `Defer[Pi a + Pi b + a + b + c] //. {a + b + c -> B, a + b -> A}`? In this case due to Pi the substitution doesn't take place any more..

Comment: @hal, for `//.` (`ReplaceRepeated`) see [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html), the section Properties and Relations. If `a`, `b`, `c` appear with coefficients, you can try a more general pattern `Defer[Pi a + Pi b +  a + b + c] //. {  a + b + c -> B, 
  x_  a + x_  b :> x A}`  (or `Defer[Pi a + Pi b +  a + b + c] //. {  a + b + c -> B, 
  _.  a + _.  b :> A}`  if you the drop `Pi`)

Comment: I have one more question though. Because the expression that I am going to apply these rules might have coefficient `1`, when  I apply the above pattern matching I want also to include this case but somehow it doesn't work. For example `Defer[Pi a + Pi b + a + b + c] //. {c1_ a + c1_ b + c1_ c -> c1 B, 
  c2_ a + c2_ b -> c2 A}` doesn't work for the first substitution. Is there anything that I can do about that?

Comment: @kglr, the Default pattern `_. a + _. b :> A` matches too widely, should be something like `i_. a + i_. b -> i A` or even something like `i_. a + j_. b :> With[{k = First@MinimalBy[{i, j}, Abs]}, k A + (i - k) a + (j - k) b]`.

Comment: @hal, try the pattern `c1_.` (which matches 1 for multiplication and 0 for addition):  `Defer[Pi a + Pi b + a + b + c] //. {c1_. a + c1_. b + c1_. c -> c1 B, 
   c2_. a + c2_. b -> c2 A} // First`

Comment: @Roman, right; good point. For the case `Pi a + Pi b + a + b + c`, it may also make sense to have more specific `Pi a + Pi b -> A` or ``Pi a + Pi b -> Pi A` .

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work i tested it despite i'm sorry i'm kind of beginner

```
l0 = Superscript[Subscript[L, 0], "+"];
l1 = Superscript[Subscript[L, 0], "-"];
l2 = Superscript[Subscript[L, 0], "+"];
l3 = Superscript[Subscript[L, 0], "-"];
l4 = Subscript[L, 1];

s1 == l0 + l1 /. s1 -> a;
s2 == l2 + l3 + l4 /. s2 -> b;

s3 = s1 + s2
```

Comment: sometimes using /. Would be fast way to subtitle or replace something

Comment: Have you tried evaluating your code more than once? Because you define `s1` as a function of itself, you get different results each time.

Comment: you right while this surprised me !
its still work fine unless our friend want to go further with the code or show his full question so we help further!

Comment: i should have done == not = on what you said

Comment: try it now work just fine